Inverse probability weighting vs importance sampling
What is the difference between inverse probability weighting and importance sampling?
From their Wikipedia pages:

Inverse probability weighting is a statistical technique for estimating quantities related to a population other than the one from which the data was collected.


Importance sampling is a Monte Carlo method for evaluating properties of a particular distribution, while only having samples generated from a different distribution than the distribution of interest.

Aren't these identical? Amusingly, they never refer to each other within each page.
On the technical side, I also don't see a difference. They're both correcting for the sampling distribution by dividing the estimator with the probability of being sampled.

Inverse probability weights are used in many contexts in probability and statistics. So while the mathematical form is similar, the contexts differ (greatly) leading to different terminologies. IPW is typically used in an estimation context for causal effect estimators by adjusting for sampling bias. IS is used in a Monte Carlo context for numerically generating draws from an unknown distribution.

@Relevance Is it correct then to say that IS is in the context where a different sampling distribution is deliberately chosen for specific goals (e.g. variance reduction), while IPW is when the sampling distribution was already chosen by external reasons and now we have to deal with it?

I am not an expert in IPW, but the inverse probability weights in IPW are typically themselves estimated using conditional models, such as propensity score estimators. IS has much wider variety of use cases, including, but certainly not limited to parametric estimation, which might itself include causal effect estimation.
